# re: matching 'a href' tag

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing

I have this simple program that takes in a file from stdin and output only the host (example:  returning only HOST.

Except when I run cat sample.html | python program.py right now it outputs *href"=google.com*

I want it to remove the *'href="* part and have it only output google.com, but when I tried removing it from my re, it became even worse. Thoughts?

```
import re
import sys

s = sys.stdin.read()
lines=s.split('\n')

match = re.search(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', s) #here
if match:
    print match.group(0)
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Why are you parsing HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/908494)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you reference group(0) when it should be group(1) which holds the actual match result.

```
if match:
   print match.group(1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering, I noticed my regex doesn't work if it's href='text' with single quotations marks or not using quotation marks, how do I also add that to my regex?

Comment: Actually it does catch those cases.

Comment: it's strange because I tested it and it only returned the ones case with the "" but not single quotations :/ Thanks though.